# Mutiple instances of same DAG in airflow are failing without any logs

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to place multiple instances of the same dag in google cloud composer dags folder and trying to run them in airflow. What is happening is that apart from the first instance all other instances are failing and not producing any logs. These instances do not even go in the running state and fail instantly after getting queued. 
And since there are no logs i cant even debug anything.

Comment: Can you provide the DAG code you are trying to run? Please have a look to the "how to ask" guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by multiple instance of same DAG?

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I actually had a space in the dag name and hence it was not running. Stack driver had created logs for the same but composer did not produce any logs for the same.